# GWT:how to return a Button in buttoncelltable

Tags: gwt

I have this buttoncell

It's returning a string, but can i return an actual button instead of this `string "ReList"`, to which I can add `ClickHandler`, which i can disable, hide etc.
(as i want to disable/hide this cell)

```
 ButtonCell reListCell = new ButtonCell();
 reListColumn = new Column<EmployerJobs, String>(reListCell) {

   @Override
   public String getValue(EmployerJobs object) {        
       return "ReList";         
   }
 };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a [FieldUpdater](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/FieldUpdater.html) to the Column. See [here](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellSampler) for details.

```
ButtonCell reListCell = new ButtonCell();
 reListColumn = new Column<EmployerJobs, String>(reListCell) {
   @Override
   public String getValue(EmployerJobs object) {        
       return "ReList";         
   }
 };
reListColumn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<EmployerJobs,String>() {
   @Override
   public void update(int index, EmployerJobs object, String value) {
        Window.alert("You clicked " + object.someField());
      }
});
```

Comment: but in that case if i want to disable my button for some fields ,what can i do ,if i dont want to show any button in some of the rows

Comment: You can override the render method of your buttoncell and then set the  disabled attribut to true. Note: The ``ButtonCell`` doesn't use the ``Button`` Widget but renders HTML directly (for performance reasons)